# Kubernetes: Sidecar deployment pattern to side-load UI artifacts to ngnix container

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, containers, sidecar

This is a question on Kubernetes deployment pattern for web applications. We have a web app that supports customisation, and the customised UI artifacts are exposed on a separate context root...

- `/webapp` - default web application
- `/webapp-ext` - customised UI artifacts for the web application

HTTP requests for customised pages/widgets will be routed to `/webapp-ext` (the web app handles this well). In order to decouple the change rollout for default and customised UI artifacts, we would like to manage them separately from a deployment standpoint.

We are exploring different options here...

**Option 1**: Run 2 Nginx containers as sidecars, with `/webapp` and `/webapp-ext` context roots, listening on ports 8080 and 8081 respectively.

**Option 2**: Run a Nginx container with `/webapp` and a sidecar container with the UI artifacts for `/webapp-ext`. Mount the contents from the sidecar to the Ngnix container, so that the single Ngnix container can host both `/webapp` and `/webapp-ext` context roots. (Alternatively, wondering whether `initConatiner` can also be an option here, as the sidecar need not continue to run once the custom UI artifacts are copied over to the Ngnix container)

**Option 3**: Run a Ngnix container with `/webapp`, and download custom UI artifacts from an external location (e.g., AWS S3 bucket) on container startup (say, using `curl`)

With **Option 2** and **Option 3**, we can avoid running multiple Ngnix processes/containers - instead, the custom UI artifacts are side-loaded or downloaded into the main container. But, this will be an apparent deviation from the container philosophy of running self-contained, immutable containers.

It will be helpful, if you can help me understand the pros and cons of these approaches and which one would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're talking about some static artifacts being served from something like `/usr/share/nginx/www`

Cleanest and most elegant solution would be 4th option of having two separate k8s deployments / services for each application type.

1. `webapp` would have separate nginx pods serving static content with this service only.. there would be `webapp` k8s service in front of it routing traffic to the pods
2. same thing for `webapp-ext`

In other words you'd be running two applications completely separate from each other. You could deploy `webapp` 5 times a day and never touch `webapp-ext` or viceversa.

How you'd get your artefacts into `webapp-ext` is up to you but in general I don't think downloading something through init container is good solution. Just build your image upfront with all your artefacts baked into the image. You can build new image any time you change something through some CI pipeline. As you said it's deviation from container philosophy and everyone tries to avoid it.

Kubernetes ingress is way how to route L7 HTTP traffic on kubernetes clusters. See the article: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

1. `www.example.com/webapp` traffic would go to `webapp` service
2. `www.example.com/webapp-ext` traffic would go to `webapp-ext` service

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I intentionally avoided the 4th option of separate deployments, as I really wanted to group these components as a single logical unit. Though these containers are not directly dependent on each other, the application can't work if both the containers are up and running. And the scaling requirements of both containers will be similar. 

Another reason to group them is to avoid the need to for running multiple istio sidecars (we use istio to manage traffic workloads). Additional sidecar means additional cpu/memory, which I wanted to avoid.

Comment: More context - we are running these workloads at a large scale. We would end up having 200+ deployments of `webapp` (not pods/replicas, deployments... 1 deployment per customer, and 200 such customers).

Comment: Deployment is not equal to single application. If you deploy application + database pods the application also doesn't work without database. It's still not reason to collocate them so single pod.

Comment: Also what about option five to simply build nginx image with both /webapp and /webapp-ext artifacts built in already? Any time you need to change one or other you need to rebuild whole image but is it really a big deal with automated CI/CD?